# How to get all documents in a collection from Firestore in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve all documents from the 'users' collection in my firestore DB:

[image]

For now I'd just like to retrieve each `userName` and `Role`. I have seen a lost of similar questions but they always use snapshots like this:

```
async getMarkers() {
  const events = await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        console.log('LOG 1', doc.data());
        return doc.data();
      });
    });
  console.log('LOG 2', events);
  return events;
}
```

But I think my project structure is a bit different.

Here is my index.js located in the firebase folder:

### Index.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDVyMU4XZEaLmT17ksu2S6ndnypNwL555s",
    authDomain: "cyberpunkprojv1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://cyberpunkprojv1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "cyberpunkprojv1",
    storageBucket: "cyberpunkprojv1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "837539155372",
    appId: "1:837539155372:web:e52a4bd30fd0c9da29be09",
    measurementId: "G-JGRZT5YX0Q"
};

export const init = () => {
    return firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}


export const createUser = (user) =>
    firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.userName).set(user); // I need to know how to create a subcollection when creating a document


export const getAllUsers = () => firebase.firestore().collection('users').get(); //This line does not work right now.
```

What I am primarily concerned with here is  `getAllUsers`. Note though that `createUser` works exactly as intended.

This is in another .js screen in which `getAllUsers` is called:

### CharacterViewScreen.js

```
   React.useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('Select Screen loaded.')
        userFetch();
      },[])

    const userFetch = async () => {
        try{
            await firebase.init();
    
            const users = await firebase.getAllUsers();
            console.log(users);
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

The function runs correctly however this is what is logged in the console:

### Console

```
Select Screen loaded.
t {
  "SP": null,
  "gP": t {
    "Je": Array [],
    "Ze": "F",
    "collectionGroup": null,
    "en": t {
      "Ye": "users|f:|ob:__name__asc,",
      "collectionGroup": null,
      "endAt": null,
      "filters": Array [],
      "limit": null,
      "orderBy": Array [
        t {
          "dir": t {
            "name": "asc",
          },
          "field": e {
            "len": 1,
            "offset": 0,
            "segments": Array [
              "__name__",
            ],
          },
          "wn": true,
        },
      ],
      "path": e {
        "len": 1,
        "offset": 0,
        "segments": Array [
          "users",
        ],
      },
      "startAt": null,
    },
    "endAt": null,
    "filters": Array [],
    "limit": null,
    "path": e {
      "len": 1,
      "offset": 0,
      "segments": Array [
        "users",
      ],
    },
    "startAt": null,
    "tn": Array [
      t {
        "dir": t {
          "name": "asc",
        },
        "field": e {
          "len": 1,
          "offset": 0,
          "segments": Array [
            "__name__",
          ],
        },
        "wn": true,
      },
    ],
  },
  "iP": undefined,
  "metadata": t {
    "fromCache": false,
    "hasPendingWrites": false,
  },
  "nP": t {
    "$E": t {
      "tl": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "BE": FirebaseAppImpl {
      "automaticDataCollectionEnabled_": false,
      "container": ComponentContainer {
        "name": "[DEFAULT]",
        "providers": Map {
          "app" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "app",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => [Circular],
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "app",
          },
          "platform-logger" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "platform-logger",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "PRIVATE",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "platform-logger",
          },
          "fire-core-rn-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-core-rn-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-core-rn-version",
          },
          "fire-js-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-js-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-js-version",
          },
          "auth" => Provider {
            "component": Object {
              "instanceFactory": [Function instanceFactory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "auth",
              "serviceProps": Object {
                "ActionCodeInfo": Object {
                  "Operation": Object {
                    "EMAIL_SIGNIN": "EMAIL_SIGNIN",
                    "PASSWORD_RESET": "PASSWORD_RESET",
                    "RECOVER_EMAIL": "RECOVER_EMAIL",
                    "VERIFY_EMAIL": "VERIFY_EMAIL",
                  },
                },
                "ActionCodeURL": [Function d],
                "Auth": [Function Lm],
                "AuthCredential": [Function kg],
                "EmailAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "Error": [Function M],
                "FacebookAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "GithubAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "GoogleAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "OAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "PhoneAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "RecaptchaVerifier": [Function d],
                "SAMLAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "TwitterAuthProvider": [Function d],
              },
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => Object {
                "apiKey": "AIzaSyDVyMU4XZEaLmT17ksu2S6ndnypNwL555s",
                "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
                "authDomain": "cyberpunkprojv1.firebaseapp.com",
                "currentUser": null,
              },
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "auth",
          },
          "auth-internal" => Provider {
            "component": Object {
              "instanceFactory": [Function instanceFactory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "auth-internal",
              "type": "PRIVATE",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => Object {
                "addAuthTokenListener": [Function bound ],
                "getToken": [Function bound ],
                "getUid": [Function bound ],
                "removeAuthTokenListener": [Function bound ],
              },
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "auth-internal",
          },
          "fire-auth-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-auth-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-auth-version",
          },
          "database" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": true,
              "name": "database",
              "serviceProps": Object {
                "DataSnapshot": [Function DataSnapshot],
                "Database": [Function Database],
                "INTERNAL": Object {
                  "dataUpdateCount": [Function dataUpdateCount],
                  "forceLongPolling": [Function forceLongPolling],
                  "forceWebSockets": [Function forceWebSockets],
                  "interceptServerData": [Function interceptServerData],
                  "isWebSocketsAvailable": [Function isWebSocketsAvailable],
                  "setSecurityDebugCallback": [Function setSecurityDebugCallback],
                  "stats": [Function stats],
                  "statsIncrementCounter": [Function statsIncrementCounter],
                },
                "Query": [Function Query],
                "Reference": [Function Reference],
                "ServerValue": Object {
                  "TIMESTAMP": Object {
                    ".sv": "timestamp",
                  },
                },
                "TEST_ACCESS": Object {
                  "ConnectionTarget": [Function RepoInfo],
                  "DataConnection": [Function PersistentConnection],
                  "RealTimeConnection": [Function Connection],
                  "forceRestClient": [Function forceRestClient],
                  "hijackHash": [Function hijackHash],
                  "queryIdentifier": [Function queryIdentifier],
                },
                "enableLogging": [Function enableLogging],
              },
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "database",
          },
          "fire-rtdb-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-rtdb-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-rtdb-version",
          },
          "storage" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function factory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": true,
              "name": "storage",
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-rtdb-version",
          },
          "storage" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function factory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": true,
              "name": "storage",
              "serviceProps": Object {
                "Reference": [Function Reference],
                "Storage": [Function Service],
                "StringFormat": Object {
                  "BASE64": "base64",
                  "BASE64URL": "base64url",
                  "DATA_URL": "data_url",
                  "RAW": "raw",
                },
                "TaskEvent": Object {
                  "STATE_CHANGED": "state_changed",
                "TaskState": Object {
                  "CANCELED": "canceled",
                  "ERROR": "error",
                  "PAUSED": "paused",
                  "RUNNING": "running",
                  "SUCCESS": "s...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)
```

I feel like I have to be pretty close but I have no ides what that users object that is being logged actually is. Can I actually do this using this approach or do I have to use the snapshots like in the example? My method at least works a little bit because I created all of those database entries useing the `createUser` method in Index.js that is called a similar way in another view.

If I need to add any additional information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default string output of the [QuerySnapshot](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/querysnapshot) object returned by Firestore is not going to be helpful to you.  You should write code to check and iterate its results, using the provided API, as shown in the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#snapshots):

```
const users = await firebase.getAllUsers();
// users is a QuerySnapshot
if (users.size() > 0) {
    users.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data())
    })
}
else {
    // decide what you want to do if no results
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you so much! I'm an idiot for not having found that. Btw, .size() isnt a function. It's users.size.